# ElasticSearch 150k query takes several minutes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query roughly 150k docs from ES. My 150k docs sum up to 9.24GB in disk space and I am using the scroll API and fetch 10'000 per scroll. It takes well beyond 5min to query it and runs into memory problems (requires more than 6GB of RAM). Now I tried several approaches:

_source: regular filtering. From the 70 key-value pairs per document I only need 4 fields

```
 {
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "updateTime": {
        "lte": 10000000000000000
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "id.identifierOne",
    "id.identifierTwo",
    "arrivalTime",
    "updateTime"
  ],
  "sort": [
    "_doc"
  ]
}
```

_stored_field: in order to omit the huge overhead of the full doc, I store 4 fields during index creation

```
{
  "size": 100000,
  "stored_fields": [
    "updateTime",
    "id.identifierOne",
    "id.identifierTwo",
    "arrivalTime"
  ],
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "updateTime": {
        "lte": 10000000000000000
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_doc"
  ]
}
```

Both run in equal time. The other weird thing I noticed with the _source version is, every 10'000 scroll leads to longer query times for the next batch and increasing RAM.

I strongly suspect an error in my config or query. Waiting for several minutes seems to be way too long.

My config is: 5 shards on one node only. The pod scales to 2CPU's with 6GB of RAM. Index creation is done like this

```
 {
      "mappings": {
        "doc": {
          "dynamic": "false",
          "properties": {
            "id.identifierOne": {
              "type": "long",
              "store": true
            },
            "id.identifierTwo": {
              "type": "text",
              "store": true
            },
            "arrivalTime": {
              "type": "long",
              "store": true
            },
            "updateTime": {
              "type": "long",
              "store": true
            }
          }
        },
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a possibility to reduce the query time to under a minute?

Any help or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the use case here? why do you need so many records? It's taking so long because you're requesting a very large amount of data.

Comment: **Use case** is: loads every id (4 small fields) from all records. Each record have of cause more informations and is up to 30MB.